# creating new desktops in ubuntu 20.04 lts

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I am relatively new to ubuntu.
I am running ubuntu 20.04 lts on an hp laptop pavilion core i3.
I have ONE monitor.

I have been indoctrinated with windows and am used to windows 10.
I want to learn ubuntu.

One of the main things I like about windows is being able to create new desktops;
[Windows] + [CTRL] + D.   =  new desktop
I can create as many desktops as I need and maneuver through them by doing this;
[Windows] + [CTRL] + >   or [Windows] + [CTRL] + <

I can have ten desktops.
example:
desktop 1 = word document,
desktop 2 = dictionary.com,
desktop 3 = wikipedia.org,
desktop 4 = another word document,
desktop 5 = an excel spreadsheet,
etc.

How can I do this in Ubuntu??
Thank you.

Comment: We generally call them "Workspaces." A "Desktop" means some thing else in this community; using the wrong term can confuse people. Now that you know the correct term to Google, you should have no problems.

Comment: Welcome, I'd say a good first question tbh